# Differentiating each Line with different type in `ggsurv` plots (or in `plot`)

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, ggally

I am using `Rstudio`. I am using `ggsurv` function from `GGally` package for drawing Kaplan-Meier curves for my data (for survival analysis), from tutorial [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/07/creating-good-looking-survival-curves-the-ggsurv-function/). I am using it instead of `plot` because `ggsurv` takes care of legends by itself.

As shown on the link, multiple curves are differentiated by color. **I want to differentiate based on linetype.** The tutorial does not seem to have any option for that. Following is my command:

```
surv1 <- survfit(Surv(DaysOfTreatment,Survived)~AgeOnFirstContactGroup)
print(ggsurv(surv1, lty.est = 3)+ ylim(0, 1))
```

`lty.est=3`(or 2) gives same dashed lines for all the lines. I want differently dashed line for each line. Using `lty=type` gives error:`object 'type' not found`. And `lty=type` would work in `ggplot` but `ggplot` does not directly deal with `survfit` plots.

Please show me how to differentiate curves by linetype in either `ggsurv` or simple `plot` (although I would prefer `ggsurv` because it takes care of legends)

Comment: @lmo I can't find example or tutorial for plotting `survfit` object. There are examples for normal x-y plot: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320148/ggplot2-draw-dashed-lines-of-same-colour-as-solid-lines-belonging-to-different-g) and [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/linetype). But they use `aes` which I am unable to figure out how to use in plotting `survfit`. Can you please write a couple of lines and show me how that can be done? I am trying a lot of things but none of them are working.

Comment: @lmo This is the same link that I have mentioned in the question!

Comment: It's also a 3-year-old link. `ggsurv` isn't as flexible as one would like. I would recommend creating your own version of the function to use `linetype` instead of color [or picking a more more recent option](http://r-addict.com/2016/05/23/Informative-Survival-Plots.html).

Comment: idu..can you not use `lty.est` ?, where you pass the number of linetypes ... so if you have two strata then `lty.est = c(1,3)` and if you dont want the lines coloured then `ggsurv(sf.sex, surv.col="black", lty.est=c(1,3))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation for ggsurv

> lty.est:  linetype of the survival curve(s). Vector length should be
>   either 1 or equal to the number of strata.

So, to get a different line type for each stratum, set lty.est equal to a vector of the same length as the number of lines you are plotting, with each value corresponding to a different line type.

**For example**, using the lung data from the `survival` package

```
library(GGally)
library(survival)
data(lung)
surv1 <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurv(surv1, lty.est=c(1,2), surv.col = 1)
```

Gives the following plot

[image]

You can add ggplot themes or other ggplot elements to the plot too.  For example, we can improve the appearance using the cowplot theme as follows

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
ggsurv(surv1, lty.est=c(1,2), surv.col = 1) + theme_cowplot()
```

[image]

If you need to change the legend labels after differentiating by linetype, then you can do it this way

```
ggsurv(surv1, lty.est=c(1,2), surv.col = 1) +
  guides(colour = FALSE) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name   = 'Sex', breaks = c(1,2), labels = c('Male', 'Female'))
```

[image]

Comment: Changing the legend labels afterwards like you have shown, gives output: `Scale for 'linetype' is already present. Adding another scale for 'linetype', which will replace the existing scale.` And the legends are not changed. How to rectify this?

Comment: It works perfectly for me on R 3.2.2, with GGally v 1.01 and ggplot2 v 2.1.0.  Have you made sure that your packagesand R are up to date? You will certainly see the warning that the new scale is replacing the old one, but you can safely ignore that, as that is what you want.  Can you post a minimal reproducible example required to reproduce your problem (i.e. both the code *and* data you are using).  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to post the information people need to help you.

Comment: By the way, if you used `guides(linetype = FALSE)` rather than what I posted in my answer (`guides(colour = FALSE)`), this will generate the  behaviour you describe.