# Pandas plot line with different line styles?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting several lines on the same plot, using the `ggplot` style. With this style, the lines become all solid lines. So the visibility is not good. How can I change each line to have different styles, e.g., one with dashed lines, or something?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
ax.set_title('Loss curve', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Loss')
ax.set_xlabel('Epoch')
df1.plot.line(ax=ax,x='epoch',y=["train_loss"])
df2.plot.line(ax=ax,x='epoch',y=["train_loss"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Pass `linestyle='--'` to the plot command? Other line styles [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html).

Comment: This thread is what you looking for --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320148/ggplot2-draw-dashed-lines-of-same-colour-as-solid-lines-belonging-to-different-g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `linestyle` to change each line with different styles.

Here is an example :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
ax.set_title('Loss curve', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Loss')
ax.set_xlabel('Epoch')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'epoch' : [10,20,30,40,50,60],
                    'train_loss' : [6,5,4,3,2,1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'epoch' : [10,20,30,40,50,60],
                    'train_loss' : [6.5,5.5,4.5,3.5,2.5,1.5]})

df1.plot.line(ax=ax,x='epoch',y=["train_loss"], 
              linewidth= 1.5, linestyle='-.')
df2.plot.line(ax=ax,x='epoch',y=["train_loss"], linewidth= 1.5,
              linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

The above code will show the graph as following :
[image]

At [plt.plot.line()](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), you can check more styles as solid, dash, dash-dot, dotted, and etc.